# Failed to load resource Asp.net MVc Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm developing a web app. In my wwwroot directory i have a login-form directory which includes css js and images. In my layout i gave a path for them. My goal is loading a image background of login.cshtml which is changed by script.js.You can see that i path my script in my layout. When i opened my login page images can not be loaded by controller and i checked in browser. The error is 
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" http://localhost:3577/Account/assets/img/backgrounds/3.jpg. What is wrong i couldn't solve it ?

script.js

```
Query(document).ready(function() {

    /*
        Fullscreen background
    */
    $.backstretch([
                    "assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg"
                  , "assets/img/backgrounds/3.jpg"
                  , "assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg"
                 ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});

    /*
        Form validation
    */
    $('.login-form input[type="text"], .login-form input[type="password"], .login-form textarea').on('focus', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    $('.login-form').on('submit', function(e) {

        $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });


});
```

_layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <environment names="Development">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/login-form/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/login-form/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/login-form/assets/css/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/login-form/assets/css/style.css">

    </environment>


</head>
<body>
<div>
    @RenderBody()        
</div>

<environment names="Development">

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/login-form/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/login-form/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/login-form/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/login-form/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

</environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)                         

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you added app.UseStaticFiles(); at the top of the Configure method of the Startup class?

Comment: Yes i have added.

Comment: Isn't the path supposed to be like **/lib/login-form/assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg** in script.js?

Comment: i have done it as you said but things didn't changed.

Comment: If your static files are in wwwroot under login-form folder then you have to remove the lib folder from the path. But maybe it would be easier if you post a small screenshot about the static file structure in Visual Studio?